# Why "FormDataMultiPart" type parameter is treated differently

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am writing little web app uploading the file to a web server. I got everything working, but I became puzzled by the fact that almost all parameters send from the client (browser) must be on the server side injected with the word `@FormDataParam` except `FormDataMultiPart` type parameter.
Can somebody explain that to me, please?

Regards,
Janusz

Comment: Because the web browser sends *all* form values of a form with `multipart/form-data` encoding as part of the multipart content, so you need to say you want the value from there, otherwise the server will try to extract the value from a query parameter, and since the browser didn't send any query parameters, you'd get all null values.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, all entity body parameters are the parameter without any annotation. Such as with JSON or XML, you would see

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public Response post(RequestEntity entity) {
}
```

Here, the `MessageBodyReader` that handles JSON or XML would be used to handle deserializing the entity stream into the `RequestEntity`.

This is the same with `FormDataMultiPart`. There is a `MessageBodyReader` to handle deserializing the entire multipart stream and creating the `FormDataBodyPart` for the Jersey runtime to pass to the resource method when it is called.

`@FormDataParam` is treated more like `@FormParam`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, etc. We can have multiple parameters. Each parameter for this annotation represent a single *part* of the multipart request.

So we have the option to either get the entire request into a single entity with `FormDataMultiPart`; in which case we would extract the parts *programmatically*. Or we can *declaratively* extract each part using the `@FormDataParam` annotation, where the value of the annotation would be the *name* of the part.

If we used `FormDataMultiPart`, we would have to extract all the parts manually from it. We would use this in such a case where the name of each part is not known. Or there are many parts, where declaring each one is tedious work or ugly to the developer.