# Multiple files upload in a REST service using Jersey

Tags: java, curl, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

Quite a few links here that suggest using `multipart/form-data` and how to get the file upload here. Couldn't really find one for a combination of multiple files uploaded via CURL command and to a REST service accepting `FormDataMultiPart`.

The code in service currently looks like :

```
@javax.ws.rs.POST
@javax.ws.rs.Path("/sample-bulk")
@javax.ws.rs.Consumes(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response bulkUpload(@FormDataParam("file") org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {
    log.info("{} log", multiPart.getField("file"));
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

and the CURL I am trying to call the service is as :

> curl -X POST
>   "http://localhost:37200/api/sample-bulk"
>   -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@/Users/naman/Desktop/Media/video.mp4;type=video/mp4"

But it results in `multiPart` being `null` at the service and of course NPE.

Anything silly that I've missed here?

Comment: A [sample suggestion online](https://www.geekmj.org/jersey/jax-rs-multiple-files-upload-example-408/) to use `FormDataMultiPart` as I start to wonder if this is even supported somehow.

Comment: You don't use `@FormDataParam` when you use `FormDataMultiPart`. `FormDataMultiPart` is the _entire_ request body (_all_ parts). You use `@FormDataParam` when you want to get _individual_ parts, where you would use the part's name as the annotation value. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122910/2587435) might provide some clarification. Also look at the [Jersey docs for Multipart](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9096)

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks a lot for the response. I would look into the documentation in a while, though I could with the minimal example verify that removing the `@FormDataParam` works adding value to the `multiPart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the method parameter (the presence of the `@FormDataParam`)

```
public Response bulkUpload(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataMultiPart multiPart) {}
```

`@FormDataParam` is used when you want to *declaratively* extract individual parts from the multipart request, whereas `FormDataMultiPart` is used to get an entire multipart body and *programmatically* extract each part. [It's possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33689000/2587435) to have a nested multipart where a complete multipart is an individual part (in which case what you have would work), but this is not the case here.

If you remove the `@FormDataParam("file")`, then it will work as expected. You can start extracting parts out of the multipart using the method you are using `getField(fieldName)`. This will give you a `FormDataBodyPart` for each part you extract. You can get the data with `FormDataBodyPart#getValueAs(InputStream.class)` if you want that part as an `InputStream`, or you can use `File.class` or `byte[].class`, whatever your preference. This is how to extract data from the `FormDataMultiPart`.

Each part has it's own name and you extract the part using that name. In the case of your cURL request, you sent one part, and the part's name is `file`. i.e. `"file=@/Users/..."`. So if you want to send another part, just add another parameter with a different name<sup>1</sup>, [as mentioned by Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56954286/2587435):

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:37200/api/sample-bulk"\
     -H "accept: application/json"\
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"\
     -F "file1=@/Users/naman/Desktop/Media/video.mp4"\
     -F "file2=@/Users/naman/Desktop/Media/another_video.mp4"
```

As I mentioned earlier, `@FormDataParam` is used to extract parts declaratively. You use the part's name as the annotation value. So with the previous cURL command, you could do.

```
public Response bulkUpload(
        @FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1,
        @FormDaraParam("file1") FormDataContentDisposition file1Fdcd,
        @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2,
        @FormDaraParam("file2") FormDataContentDisposition file2Fdcd) {
}
```

You can get information about the part, such as the file name from the `FormDataContentDisposition`.

#### See also

- [Why “FormDataMultiPart” type parameter is treated differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56122459/2587435)
- [Jersey documentation for its multipart support (on the server side)](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9096)
- [File upload along with other object in Jersey restful web service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27609569/2587435)

---

#### Footnotes

1. Parts can have the same name also, e.g.

   ```
   -F file=@path_to_file1
   -F file=@path_to_file2
   ```

   This is the reason when you try to get a part programmatically, you get a list of FormDataBodyParts instead of a single object i.e

   ```
   FormDataMultiPart multiPart = ...
   List<FormDataBodyPart> files = multiPart.getField("file");
   ```

   And if you wanted to get them declaratively, you would use a `List` instead of a single object type

   ```
   public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") List<InputStream> files) { ... }
   ```

Comment: I use the way you want to handle multipart. I did formData.append('file', file.name, file.data); formData.append('testObj', JSON.stringyfy(testObj)) in service.ts file. And used multipart on REST to get "testObj" and "file" but getting NPE

Answer (score 2):

```
Use this parameter 

public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("files") List<FormDataBodyPart> file) 

Use for loop

 for (int j = 0; j < files.size(); j++) {
   FormDataBodyPart this_formDataBodyPartFile = files.get(j);
   ContentDisposition this_contentDispositionHeader = this_formDataBodyPartFile
                                                    .getContentDisposition();
   InputStream this_fileInputStream = this_formDataBodyPartFile.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
                                            FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail = (FormDataContentDisposition) this_contentDispositionHeader;

//Write the code upload code   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using separate -F flag for every multipart entry, something like that:

> curl -X POST
>   "http://localhost:37200/api/sample-bulk"
>   -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@/Users/naman/Desktop/Media/video.mp4" -F "type=video/mp4"